# Multitrack recording on mackie pro fx 12v

Tags: audio-recording, mixer, guitar, drum, recorder-mixer

I'm trying to figure out whether this mixer model suits my needs.

I have an electronic drum kit, and an electric guitar which I want to record.
The drums need left and right input. The guitar needs a Hi-z input.
I'm not sure if I understand correctly - does the mixer only has the option of multitrack recording from the first two channels? those are the only channels that have the Hi-z input, and in that case I can't record the guitars along with the drums at the same time (I can only plug the drums L+R to channels 5-6/7-8/9-10). If I plug the L+R to inputs 1 and 2 I have no input left for the guitar.

It seems like in order to record the drums I can't record (or even play along with) the guitar. Do I understand correctly?

Perhaps I'm overcomplicating things - I'm a total newbie. What are my options of recording both instruments with this mixer? (assuming I do want to have them both in separate signals and be able to edit them later).

Comment: If you need to be able to simultaneously record stereo drums plus guitar on your computer & have them on different tracks, then this will not suit. You need a multi-channel interface. Most consumer & semi pro recording gear has 2 in, 2 out, no matter how many channels it has as input to itself, it can only transfer 2 at a time to the computer. [This does appear to have switchable bus 3 & 4, but from what I've seen, enabling it disables bus 1&2]. You'll need more. I'd visit an actual physical music store & talk to them about what you need.

Comment: I see, thank you. The problem I had when consulting in physical stores is that each sells a specific brand and it's hard to compare their recommendations and translate them to an objective decision. I understood that in general it's better to buy a mixer and an audio interface separately to get what I need. I did ran into models like soundcraft Signature 12 MTK that have 12 in/12 out. I thought that it would be easier for me as a beginner to have all the functionality in a single device, but it's a bit pricey. Are you familiar with that model?

Comment: Not really, sorry. I haven't used hardware mixers in a long time. Last one I had was the Yamaha 02R… which was quite some time ago.

Comment: You don’t need a mixer. Search for a 4 channel USB interface and that will suit your needs. You will need a DAW that allows multitrack recording too. If you are using Audacity (like many beginners) that doesn’t have multitracking.

Comment: I think most beginners record one instrument at a time. Like record drums, then record guitar while listening to the drum playback.